Design of a string
Consider a string with a mass attached. The string is fixed to the support above, and the mass is hung at the other end. Is it possible to design the string for the following two cases?

The mass is not swinging, i.e. only gravitation can be assumed to act.
The mass is swung but not entirely, i.e. the maximum angle of the string with the vertical can be assumed to be less than 90 degrees.

The unknown parameters can be assumed.
I think that the maximum stress in the string (mg for the first case and mg+mrw2 for the second case) can be equated to the tensile stress of the string. Is it correct?

Yes, but not simultaneously as you cannot be "not swinging" and "swung" at the same time. I believe you are looking for a string called a linkage.

When there is no rotation, only simple hanging of the weight
$$T= mg $$
When there is rotation:

Lowest position

We add central acceleration to gravity so tension is
$$ T= mg +  m \omega^2 L $$

Highest position Kinetic energy converts to Potential energy at height $h$ above lowest point for pendulum length $L$

$$  m (\omega L)^2/2 = mg \cdot h, ~ \omega= \frac{\sqrt{2 g h}}{L} ; $$
So back at lowest position
$$ T= mg(1+ 2h/L) $$
Since $$  T \cos \theta_{max}=mg~ $$
by static equilibrium alone and since
$$ h=L(1- \cos\theta_{max})$$
the string tension at highest position or height is
$$ T =\frac {mg} { 1- h/L}.$$

The tension at the vertical position and the mass not moving is just the weight of the mass, assuming the string's weight is too small compared to the mass.
$$T= mg$$
When the mass is swinging, the tension in the string is the sum of gravity force projected on the string and centripital force due to rotation of the mass about the fix pivot,
$$T=mgcos (\theta)+\frac{mv^2}{L}$$
where:

theta is the angle of swing, small angle!
m is the mass of the bob,
g is the acceleration due to gravity,
v is the velocity of the bob, and
L is the length of the string.

At the lowest point of the swing tension in the string is maximum.
The speed, v, is,
$$v= \sqrt{(2gL(1-cos\theta)}$$
And tension in the string,
$$T= mg+ \frac{m(2gL(1-cos\theta))}{L}$$
